# Publishing page description - where does it come from?

Tags: publishing-page

I need to create a few publishing pages in a feature event receiver.  No problem, I can get the publishing layouts, create a new publishing page based on that layout with the page URL I want, and then go back and change the Title to something more friendly, and then check in and publish the page.

However, the little page description pop-up next to the page title says "Home", no matter what I set the page title to.

[image]

So... where is it getting that "Home" string from, and how can I change it to display something relevant to each page?

(In PowerShell I examined the `PublishingPage` object's properties, the page's `SPListItem` property, and the page's `SPListItem.File` property, and I didn't see any properties set to "Home" anywhere.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is that that is the **site** description.  I was using "Blank Web Part Page" as the page template to create my pages from, but "Blank Web Part Page" is classified as a "Welcome" page.

Being a "Welcome" page, it makes sense that no matter what you title the page, it would show the description of the *site*.

(So really what I needed to do was use the "Body Only" Article type page and just throw my web parts on there.)